# Broken gnome Manjaro Linux

Tags: gnome, manjaro

I was trying to update gnome to the newest version, and there were some file conflicts with gstreamer plugins like gst-good, so I removed them manually and I expected them to be replaced as there was a conflict, but after restart I get:
`A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.`

So this is what I've tried to do :
I fully uninstalled the gnome and gstreamer and anything related to them, then I tried to reinstall them. But nothing changed after that.

Is there anything that I may be missing? Is it possible to remove gnome entirely and reinstall it to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pacman -Sgq gnome # lists all the packages that in the group
pacman -Sgq gnome | sudo pacman -Rs - # will remove everything in the group, recursively
```

**Be careful** as this will remove **everything** and you may end up without networking etc.

A *safer* way would be to install another desktop environment, e.g. Plasma and then try to manually recover GNOME through that one.

Comment: Thank you. So I'll try the second method first

Comment: If you encounter any problems, just edit your post and @ me in the comments.